# Change jQuery daterange picker to disallow a date range if it contains disabled dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created a jQuery date range picker. I am able to select the dates ranges and show them in a textbox. Now what I need is, I need to disable certain dates and assign different classes to those dates.

```
E.g. I must be able to give class A to April 2, class B to April 4 etc.
```

I have tried the results I got while I googled but nothing helped. What I am trying to do is to pass some dates and classes that should be assigned to those dates. That class should be assigned to those dates plus I must have option to enable or disable those dates.

The next thing I am trying to do is if there is a disabled date in between 2 dates, then that range cannot be selected.

```
E.g. Suppose I want to select April 2 to April 7 and April 5 is a disabled date. 
Then I could be able to select either April 2 to April 4 or April 6 to April 7.
```

That means only one range should be selectable. Please help to solve this.

Please find the fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk/):

Comment: did you mean multi-select? like [THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/)

Comment: @CJRamki No, I am not looking for this. I want it in my UI itself. To make the problem more clear I have edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create two arrays, one that maps the css Class with each Date you want to be disabled `class:date`, and one that maps the css class with the date you want to give a special class, and then:

1. Inside `beforeShowDay`, check if the date is in the disabled dates array, and if you find it, use the associated class and return false, example: `[false,"classA"]`, if not , check in the special array and return the class with true, else just do whatever you are doing right now.
2. Inside `onSelect`, check if the selected range includes any of the dates in the array and act accordingly
3. Then In the `class:date` array, you can add any `class:date` you desire to be disabled with its own class, and the code will handle it

Full working solution [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk/174/).

Notes:

1. The code disables the 22nd of April and the 15th of May (try playing with the dates)
2. The code gives a special class to the 15th of April and the 10th of May.
3. The css class is applies as a `background-color` on the `td`, it does't show properly, you will have to modify the picker's css for it to do
4. Reference that hepled me provide this answer is [**here**](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `beforeShowDay` and `onSelect` functions as shown in the following demo:

**http://jsfiddle.net/salman/H3ra3/**

The code may look daunting but it is not. The basics are as follows:

**The `dateConfig` variable**

The date information is stored in an associative array in which we store whether a date is selectable AND/OR its CSS class name.

**`beforeShowDay`**

Let `date` be the date for which the function was called
Let `date1` be the date inside start date textbox
Let `date2` be the date inside end date textbox

- If the `date` is unselectable then
  return `[false, date_class or ""]`
- If user has chosen `date1`

  - If user has chosen `date2` and `date` is between `date1 ...date2` then
    return `[true, selected_class]`
  - If `date` is less than `date1` then
    return `[false, date_class or ""]` (do not allow second date to be less than first date)
  - If `date` is equal to `date1` then
    return `[true, selected_class]` (allow second date to be same as first)
  - return `[true, date_class or ""]`

**`onSelect`**

Let `date1` be the date inside start date textbox
Let `date2` be the date inside end date textbox

- If user has chosen `date1` and `date2` then

  - Iterate over all unselectable dates
  - If an unselectable date is between `date1 ...date2` then throw an error